# How should I store multiple nested arrays, populated using Mongoose populate(), in the cache using React Query?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, react-query

Apologies if this is basic but I'm struggling to get my head around how to set this up.

I'm using MongoDB/Mongoose for my backend which returns a user object with nested arrays:

```
{
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },
  name: String,
  avatar: String,
  recommendations: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Media' }],
  watchlist: [{
    media: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Media' },
    date_added: Date,
  }],
}
```

If a user visits their watchlist or recommendations page, the nested array gets populated, using mongoose populate(), with the referenced recommendations/watchlist items that they've added.

On the frontend I'm using React Query to handle the data returned from the server. Currently visiting either of the pages returns the whole user object, if I were to cache the entire object using the query key ['user'] the nested array **not** being populated will be stored as an array of reference id's. Instead I was thinking of maybe trying to update the nested arrays using setQueryData, however this doesn't work if the page is refreshed:

```
function useWatchlist() {
  const { user } = useAuth()
  const queryClient = useQueryClient()

  const result = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['user'],
    queryFn: () => 
      axios.get(`${baseUrl}/${user.profile_id}/watchlist`).then(response => response.data)
  },  
  {onSuccess: (watchlist) => {
    queryClient.setQueryData(['user'], oldUser => {
      oldUser.watchlist === watchlist
    })
  }
  })
  return {...result, profile: result.data }
}
```

Should the recommendation/watchlist arrays instead be stored separately using different query keys - ['watchlist']/['recommendations'] or should I attempt to keep the user object structure being returned from the backend?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that yes, you should store them separately. Yet, using relative keys (e.g. ['user', 'watchlist'] and ['user', 'recommendations']) as explained [here](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/effective-react-query-keys) under **Structure**:

> Structure your Query Keys from most generic to most specific, with as many levels of granularity as you see fit in between

So, you can invalidate them both when the user is refetched.

When I store data such as the "watch list", which only changes when the user changes it, I put a `staleTime: Infinity` and use `setQueryData` in the `onSuccess` of the relevant mutation (when a user updates his watch list).

For the "recommendation list", it's different story, as it would be constantly changing by some logic in the backend. So, I would use `invalidateQuery` whenever the 'user' key is fetched (or expire the cache, if you update the list each certain interval), and populate it again, on the `onSuccess` for that query.